# One to many join with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  One table looks like

```
ORDER_ID | SHOPPER_NAME | DATE
-------------------------------
001A     | Marianna     | 08/09/2012
002A     | Jason        | 80/08/2012
```

and another table that has information on the order

```
ORDER_ID | DATA_CODE   | DATA_VALUE
----------------------------------
001A     | MILK_MONEY  | 1.20
001A     | NUM_EGGS    | 22
002A     | TOTAL_SPENT | 32.43
001A     | TOTAL_SPENT | 42.13
```

I need to get several of the data codes for a specific order.  How can I select SHOPPER_NAME, MILK_MONEY (DATA_VALUE where DATA_CODE = 'MILK_MONEY'), TOTAL_SPENT and NUM_EGGS in one row?  I have it working where I am doing 3 joins like

```
SELECT SHOPPER_NAME,
       MILK.DATA_VALUE,
       EGGS.DATA_VALUE,
       TOTAL.DATA_VALUE
FROM GROCERIES G
JOIN ORDER_INFO MILK ON MILK.ORDER_ID=G.ORDER_ID
JOIN ORDER_INFO EGGS ON EGGS.ORDER_ID=G.ORDER_ID
JOIN ORDER_INFO TOTAL ON TOTAL.ORDER_ID=G.ORDER_ID
```

However this is starting to look ugly and it does not feel right to be doing multiple joins on the same table.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pivot on your 2nd table to denormalize it somewhat or you could change your db architecture by denormalizing it a bit.  Look up MySQL PIVOT on stack overflow for more examples, but something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ORDER_ID, DATA_CODE, DATA_VALUE FROM tablename
PIVOT (sum(DATA_VALUE) FOR DATA_CODE IN ([MILK_MONEY], [NUM_EGGS], [TOTAL_SPENT])) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SHOPPER_NAME,
       (select sum(DATA_VALUE) from ORDER_INFO where DATA_CODE  = 'MILK_MONEY' and ORDER_ID = G.ORDER_ID) as 'MilkValue'
       (select sum(DATA_VALUE) from ORDER_INFO where DATA_CODE  = 'NUM_EGGS' and ORDER_ID = G.ORDER_ID) as 'EggsValue'
       (select sum(DATA_VALUE) from ORDER_INFO where DATA_CODE  = 'TOTAL_SPENT' and ORDER_ID = G.ORDER_ID) as 'TotalSpentValue'
FROM GROCERIES G
```

Use `subquerys` to get each sum (I don't know if there are more of one column or if there are totals of milk, eggs, etc; in that case, remove the `sum's`)
Each sum will be for each `Order_Id`

Comment: Is this any more efficient than the joins though?

Comment: considering that you have info in  a same column, it's very possible that you will need to do one of more join; maybe could be done with a case around Data_Code, but I'm not sure if it's possible(and I'm at work, maybe later I can try it)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT g.SHOPPER_NAME, oi.* from GROCERIES g JOIN ORDER_INFO oi on oi.ORDER_ID=G.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: This won't work.  It returns me many rows, for each order, it returns a row for every single DATA_CODE.  The example is simplified but really I will have about 35 data codes